# Python, probably a simple solution with dictionary and functions but dont know how

Tags: python, dictionary, raspberry-pi

So...I am doing a volunteer school project (building a quadcopter) and have been sitting here for a very long time trying to solve the problem...:

Basically, i was able to start the motor at a certain speed per remote control (Yes, the one youd use for TV :D)

But know, I'm struggling with adding new buttons to compare them with the input as shown in the following:

```
import serial
import time
from RPIO import PWM

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0")
ser.baudrate = 2400

motorspeed = 1000
s = PWM.Servo()

#initializing
print "\033[1;32mINITIALIZING SEQUENCE STARTED\033[1;m"
s.set_servo(27, 2000)
time.sleep(0.5)
s.set_servo(27, 1000)
time.sleep(2)
print "\033[1;32mINITIALIZING SEQUENCE COMPLETE\033[1;m"
print "\033[1;36mAWAITING PWM SIGNALS\033[1;m"

buttons = {
    "up": [32, 36, 36, 27, 219, 250, 32, 36, 36, 27, 219, 250, 32, 36, 36], 
    "button1": [32, 219, 219, 36, 196, 32, 219, 219, 36, 196, 32, 219, 219, 36, 196]}
# every button has a signature

input = []
# signature thats coming from the remote

while input != buttons[:]:
# I suspect a fault here, I want to compare all key values with the input list
   for i in range(0, 15):
        data = ser.read(1)
        print ord(data)
        input.append(ord(data))
# Every IR button has a unique "key", thats what I am comparing
    print input

    if input == buttons["button1"]:
        print ("Button pressed!")
        s.set_servo(27, motorspeed)
        time.sleep(3)
     elif input == buttons["up"]:
        s.set_servo(27, motorspeed + 100
    else:
        del input[:]
```

What the problem is: I want to compare the list called "input" with the dictionary "buttons". If one of the lists in dictionary is identical with the list "input" it should the raise motorspeed

Comment: Please explain what is not currently working out to your expectations. What inputs are you providing that are not working. What output are you getting that is not what you expect. What do you expect? In short, please make sure you provide a good [mcve] to help narrow down your problem.

Comment: What do you expect `while input != buttons[:]:` to do? Do you want to check whether each element of `input` is also in `buttons`?

Comment: Have you considered reversing the buttons dict: mapping the signature to the button name? You'd need tuples instead of lists, but since signatures are unique, they could be the keys in your buttons dict and looking for them would be faster, no need to iterate.

Comment: What the problem is: I want to compare the list called "input" with the dictionary "buttons". If one of the lists in dictionary is identical with the list "input" it should the raise motorspeed.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are looking for help on, you could try something like this:

```
buttons = {
    "up": [32, 36, 36, 27, 219, 250, 32, 36, 36, 27, 219, 250, 32, 36, 36],    
    "button1": [32, 219, 219, 36, 196, 32, 219, 219, 36, 196, 32, 219, 219, 36, 196],
    "new_button" : [1]
    # etc.
}

def up_action():
    s.set_servo(27, motorspeed+100)

def button1_action():
    s.set_servo(27, motorspeed)
    time.sleep(3)

def new_button_action():
    print "Hello! I am a new button!"

actions = {
     "up" : up_action,
     "button1" : button1_action,
     "new_button" : new_button_action,
     # etc.
}

input = ... # get your input the way you have it
            # EDIT: As others have pointed out, you may
            # want to adjust your while loop

for button_name,button_signature in buttons.iteritems():
    if input == button_signature:
        button_pressed = button_name
        break

action = actions[button_pressed]
action()
```

To add functionality for any new button you would just need to add an entry to each dictionary:

1. Add the input signature to `buttons` ({"button_name": [...input sequence...]})
2. Create a function that performs the desired behavior.
3. Add that function to `actions` ({"button_name": button_function_name})

Comment: It looks useful, thank you very much for your answer. If my guess is right, this is kinda similar to swich-case in other programming languages? Please excuse me if I am wrong, Im quite new to python as you might have recognized^^

Comment: @FabulousJob Yes, it functions quite similarly.

Answer (score 1):

This line is particularly problematic:

```
while input != buttons[:]:
```

`buttons` is a dictionary, but you are trying to copy it like a list.  Even if you did copy it correctly with `buttons.copy()`, the behavior still wouldn't be what you expect.  It appears as if you want to get all values in the dictionary and put them into one long list of `valid_inputs`.

Also, you want to check whether or not the input value is in `valid_inputs`. This is not an equality check.

```
valid_inputs = [v for vals in buttons.values() for v in vals]

while True:  # Loop forever.
    if input in valid_inputs:
        ...
        if input in buttons["button1"]:
            ...
```